# Different definitions for homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, definition

Wikipedia gives the following definition for homeomorphism between topological spaces:

> A function $f:X\to Y$ between two topological spaces is a homeomorphism if it has the following properties:
>
> - $f$ is a bijection
> - $f$ is continuous
> - the inverse function $f^{-1}$ is continuous

My general topology textbook defined homeomorphism in a different way:

> Let $(X,\tau)$ and $(Y,\tau_1)$. A function $f: X \to Y$ is said to be an homeomorphism between $X$ and $Y$ if:
>
> - $f$ is a bijection
> - $\forall U \in \tau_1, f^{-1}(U)\in\tau$
> - $\forall V \in \tau, f(V) \in \tau_1$

My question is, how are this two definitions equal? Because in the Wikipedia's definition they don't even talk about the respective topologies of $X$ and $Y$, only about continuity and In my textbook they don't even mention continuity. How can one start from the definition my textbook gave and prove that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous?

Comment: What does it mean for a function to be continuous?

Comment: A function $f: X \to Y$ is continuous if $\forall a \in X, \lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = a$, right? @GageMartin

Comment: No, for functions between topological spaces, a function is continuous if the preimage of every open set is open.

Comment: That's a definition that may be used in an analysis course but in topology, the definition involves open sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if and only if for every open set $U\subseteq Y$, $f^{-1}(U)\subseteq X$ is open. I.e. for all $U\in \tau_Y$, $f^{-1}(U)\in \tau_X$. Similarly, $f^{-1}:Y\to X$ is continuous if and only if for every open $V\subseteq X$, $f(V)\subseteq Y$ is open. I.e. for all $V\in \tau_X$, $f(V)\in \tau_Y$.

Using this you can see that these notions are equivalent.